# How do I change the GRUB boot configuration from within Windows?

Tags: grub, dual-boot

I currently dual boot Windows 7 and Fedora 14, using GRUB, with Windows 7 as my default. I know that from Fedora, I can set GRUB to boot into Fedora, overriding the default, on the next reboot. Is there a way to do this from Windows? That is, can I change the GRUB configuration permanently or semi-permanently from Windows so I don't have to be in front of my computer to boot into Fedora?

Comment: This is a thanks to Michael and an extension. There is a free driver by Paragon in public interest, which can access (with read and write permissions) to Ext2, Ext3, Ext4 partitions from Windows: https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hard part is editing your Linux filesystem from Windows. [FS Driver](http://www.fs-driver.org/) supports writing ext2, but I don't know of any good tools for ext3 or 4 (and these [SU](https://superuser.com/questions/85579/ext3-on-windows-7) and [SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/3038/what-windows-ext3-driver-should-i-use) questions aren't encouraging), let alone any other filesystems you may have used on your boot partition

But if you do manage to get write support for your boot partition from Windows, actually changing the saved default is easy. First you need to do some prep work in `/boot/grub.conf`. Change `default` to `saved`, and add `savedefault 0` (where 0 is Fedora's index in the GRUB configuration) to the Windows block so booting into Windows will reset the saved default back to Fedora

Then from Windows you can edit `/boot/grub/default`. Delete the line that's there (it'll be `default` or `0` most likely), and change it to `1` or whatever the index of your Windows install is. When you restart, GRUB will read that file (since your default is `saved`) and boot into Windows, and the `savedefault` line will change that file back to `0` for future boots

Comment: Someone's written a GUI for that: [grub-choose-default (Grub 1)](http://de.mcbf.net/david/grubchoosedefaultlegacy/), [grub-choose-default (Grub 2)](http://de.mcbf.net/david/grubchoosedefault/).

Comment: This worked for me. I had to set my `/boot` partition as `ext2` (it was `ext4`) and my limited experience doing that made that process take longer than it should have. It looks like these instructions set Fedora as the default (which I don't really want, I just want the ability to control the next boot) so I didn't follow them to the letter, but being able to edit `/boot/grub.conf` is good enough.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **Grub2Win** or other similar programs as listed 
[here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/files/).
They offer an easy user interface.

You could also completly remove Grub and boot both systems from the Windows bootloader. In order to do so you need to use tools such as **EasyBCD**.

Comment: I assume you mean Grub2Win? :)

Comment: Oh, yes, a typo.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `/boot` partition [formatted as FAT32](http://www.google.com/search?q=grub+manual+%22currently+supported+filesystem+types%22), you'll be able to edit grub's config file from both OS(es).

Answer (score 4):

Mixing different hints:

1. Under Ubuntu I changed `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` and ran `update-grub`, thus making GRUB use /boot/grub/grubenv file, but I am **not** setting `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true` (as it serves another purpose)
2. I checked available GRUB entries using this command:
   `awk -F\' '/menuentry / {print $2}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
3. Later I ran `grub-editenv - set saved_entry="Windows 10 (on /dev/sdb1)"` choosing one of the available options, so I made Windows start next time as default
4. Under Windows I mounted Linux (ext4) filesystem using Ext2Fsd
5. I edited /boot/grub/grubenv manually, commented out with `#` the previously created line `# saved_entry=Windows 10 (on /dev/sdb1)` and added a new one `saved_entry=Ubuntu`.
6. Under Ubuntu I do it vice-versa, switching between the settings, commenting out the respective line.

I think it's a neater solution than manually editing grub.cfg file directly and menu.lst has been deprecated already some time ago.

Comment: this worked fine for me except the Ext2Fsd with my Ext4 partition. I installed the 0.70 beta 3 Ext4 filesystem driver for Windows from http://www.accum.se/~bosse/, enabled the testsigned driver, rebooted windows and boom: read/write Ext4 access. :)

Answer (score 1):

Find the 'grub' folder in the hard disk and then open menu.lst with notepad now edit default=0 to default=x, where x is one less than the position of the os you want to make default. For Ex. there are three os in a system and you wanted to make the third in the list as default so you will edit it as default=2, as 3-1=2. For second os, default=1.

Answer (score 0):

I created a /boot device and selected it as `Device for boot loader installation`  and it worked.