# How can I choose which OS grub will reboot me into—before I reboot?

Tags: grub2, reboot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reboot into windows from inside my Linux shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43196/how-can-i-reboot-into-windows-from-inside-my-linux-shell)

When I reboot and want to select another kernel image in grub2 or another OS like windows I have to wait until grub comes up and then select manually the image I want. Sometimes I switch multiple times between linux and windows or between two different kernel versions, then I find it pretty annoying to select this manually.

What I want is to choose the image when I type in the reboot command. In pseudocode: `sudo reboot to windows`. Then I could get a cup of coffee and my box will automatically reboot to windows.

Is it possible to to something like this?

I guess that somebody would point out a VirtualBox solution instead. I know this, but I don't want it in this case.

Comment: [See this for how to `sudo grub-reboot ENTRY`](http://askubuntu.com/a/63079) where `ENTRY` is a number or string corresponding to a menu entry title.  Also if you play with many Linux kernels, you might appreciate [`kexec`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexec).

Comment: [Ha, I knew we had this one, too.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43196/11539)

Comment: Thanks. How can I find out the ENTRY number of a given image without rebooting (i.e. from the running system) and conversely the image name for a given ENTRY number. Best on the command line...