# grub2-reboot without root

Tags: permissions, grub2, reboot

I use the following script (based on code [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43196/54030)) to reboot to windows, so I can stop kicking myself every time I start daydreaming and miss the boot menu.

```
#!/bin/bash
ENTRY=$( grep Windows /boot/grub2/grub.cfg | head -n 1 | cut -d"'" -f2 )
echo Rebooting to \"$ENTRY\"
sudo grub2-reboot "$ENTRY" && reboot
```

However I need `sudo` and have to type a password or I get this:

```
/usr/bin/grub2-editenv: error: cannot open ‘/boot/grub2/grubenv’: Permission denied.
```

It's a symlink, `/boot/grub2/grubenv -> /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grubenv`, and owned by `root`.

The command `reboot` works just fine as a regular user in Fedora 23. How can I make `grub2-reboot` work as well, but in a secure way?

I was thinking something along the lines of a stick bit on `grub2-editenv`, but that doesn't sound good. A sticky bit on my script won't work ([a good thing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts)). Changing permissions on the file `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grubenv` would work but might open up more possibilities than intended.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities:

- Use sudo, but configure it so that this command will not ask you password (using `NOPASSWD` option)
- Set root as the owner of the script and setuid the script: `chown root.root script ; chmod u+s script`