# Specify boot device from within linux

Tags: linux, uefi, reboot, remote-management

I have two hard drives in a machine, one with CentOS and the other FreeBSD.  For remote administration, is there some way to specify the boot device from within the OS before I reboot?  This is possible within macOS, so I assume it must be possible in Linux, if I have the right tool?

It would also be cool to specify booting EFI setup, just to save the trouble of waiting and hitting F2 at the right moment.

This machine does not have IPMI capability.

Comment: Some scripts to modify the grub menu and update it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell GRUB I want to reboot into Windows—before I reboot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43196/how-can-i-tell-grub-i-want-to-reboot-into-windows-before-i-reboot)